# Making a new container with the same configuration as the old one

Tags: docker

Let's say I make a container with some flags. For instance,

```
docker run -v my_volume:/data my_cool_image
```

Now, let's say `my_cool_image` is updated to a new version. Is there a nice way to make a new container with the same `-v` flag as the old one? The container has been properly configured so that the data does not get stored in the container, so deleting the old container is not a concern.

The best solution I can find is to use `docker-compose`, but that seems a bit silly for single-container systems.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a shell script or a Docker Compose YAML file.  (Compose isn't really overkill; if you add some error handling and write out one option per line for readability, the shell script and the YAML file wind up being about the same length.)

There's nothing built in to Docker that can extract the `docker run` options from an existing container.